# NodeJS does not return JSON but gets the data from db

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api

I have an application where I need to extract data from my database ..

when I try this:

```
// get all customers
router.get('/customers', (req, res, next)  => {
  let userList = []
  // async/await - check out a client
  ;(async () => {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    try {
      const res = await client.query('SELECT id_user, username FROM users')
      userList = res.rows
      console.log(userList)
    } finally {
      // Make sure to release the client before any error handling,
      // just in case the error handling itself throws an error.
      client.release()
    }
  })().catch(err => console.log(err.stack))
  res.json("Hello there")
})
```

on the front end when calling /api/v1/customers I got

```
// 20200923123622
// http://localhost:8008/api/v1/customers

"Hello there"
```

But in the console I can see the result properly:

```
[
  { id_user: 1, username: 'admin' },
  { id_user: 2, username: 'owner' }
]
```

But when I try to return the userList as JSON

```
...
res.json(userList)
...
```

it ends up on the client as a neverending loading window (while I can still see the result in the console - the correct one)

what am I missing?

EDIT:
got that working - big thx to @kavigan

```
router.get('/customers', (req, res, next)  => {
  let userList
    (async () => {
      const res = await pool.query('SELECT id_user, username FROM users')
      userList = res.rows
    })().then((data) => {
        res.json(userList)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err.stack))

})
```

Comment: `res` is no longer the Express response object, it's whatever you got back from your database...

Comment: In addition to what @jonrsharpe said above, using ESLint with the `no-shadow` rule enabled would help you prevent mistakes like this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up with async calls, so the code correction is needed, here is how you can do it:

You either need to use then() and return the response from there as IIFE async function returns a promise and make sure you return it, in the above code you are not returning it.

```
// get all customers
router.get('/customers', (req, res, next) => {
    let userList = []
        // async/await - check out a client
        (async () => {
            //your code
        })().then((data) => {
            res.json("Hello there");
        }).catch(err => console.log(err.stack));
});
```

Or handle the async await properly like below:

```
// get all customers
router.get('/customers', async (req, res, next) => {
    let userList = []
    // async/await - check out a client
    try {
        userList = await (async () => {
            //your code
        })();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
    }
    res.json("Hello there");
});
```

Comment: hmmm weird .. I got that from the official documentation  https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling ... anyway thx I will look into it